# only one image per user with meteor CollectionCFS

Tags: meteor, image-uploading

I'm using Meteor and CollectionFS to allow users to store an image. I want that every user can store exactly one image and if he uploads a second one, the first one should be overwritten.

On client side I use the helper function to upload a file:

```
"change #imageInput": FS.EventHandlers.insertFiles(Images, {
    metadata: function (fileObj) {
        return {
            owner: Meteor.userId()
        };
    },
    after: function (error, fileObj) {
    }
});
```

server side:

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [
        new FS.Store.FileSystem("thumbs", {
            transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
                // Transform the image into a 10x10px thumbnail
                gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('125', '125').stream().pipe(writeStream);
            }
        })
    ],
});

Images.allow({
    insert: function (userId, file) {
        return userId && file.owner === userId;
    },
    update: function (userId, file, fields, modifier) {
        return userId && file.owner === userId;
    },
    remove: function (userId, file) {
        return userId && file.owner === userId;
    },
    download: function(userId, file) {
        return true;
    }
})
```

When a new image will be uploaded all images with {owner: Meteor.userId()} should be deleted.  My question is where is the place to put this? I haven't found a way to insert a hook like afterWrite on server side.

Comment: I don't really use this API but I think it should be in after event, if there is no error find all user images and remove all but this one already inserted

Comment: Seems like an `update` would be what you need.
This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479259/update-image-using-collectionfs