# Update image using collectionfs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm using collectionFS to upload an image, the thing is I want my users to be able to upload just one image and then change it(upload a new one).
I have the part in place to check if an image is already uploaded but the thing is I can't change the image that is in the db, this is the code I have to insert a new image:

```
'change .myFileInput': function(event, template) {
  FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
    var newFile = new FS.File(file);
    newFile.metadata = {
        createdBy:Meteor.userId(),
    }
    Imagess.insert(newFile, function (err, fileObj) {
      if (err){
         // handle error
      } else {
         // handle success depending what you need to do
        var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
        var imagesURL = {
          "profile.image": "/cfs/files/images/" + fileObj._id
        };
        Meteor.users.update(currentUserId, {$set: imagesURL});
      }
    });
 });
```

I don't know how to change the Imagess.insert to Imagess.update, I have already read the meteor documentation but can't find how to do it. Can anyone suggest a way or some docs where I can learn how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Speaking of not understanding how to [`update`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/update), did not you just write an update statement `Meteor.users.update(currentUserId, {$set: imagesURL});` ? Can you be more specific on what you want to do? If `Imagess` is a mongo collection you can do the same thing as what you did with `Meteor.users`.

Comment: I have basic understanding of the update statement. What I want to do is update the image, would that be Imagess.update(currentUserId, {$set: newFile, function(err,fileObj)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to update a current url image using FSCollection(in this case the image), check [this Github Issue](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/114),where Raix and Aldeed talk about some future work like `FS.File.updateData()`, but its not implemented yet.

A posible workaround will be this.

```
Template.example.events({
  'click #changeImage':function(event,template){
     var message = confirm("Do you wanna change this image?"); 
         if(message == true){
            var file = $('#changeImageInput').get(0).files[0],
                newFile = new FS.File(file);
                newFile.metadata = {
                       createdBy:Meteor.userId(),
                    }
            var query = Images.findOne({'metadata.createdBy':Meteor.userId()}) //supposing there is only one image if not use a .fetch() and a for instead.

           //removing the current image.
            Images.remove({_id:query._id},function(err,result){
           //if there is not error removing the image, insert new one with the same metadata
            if(!err){
              Images.insert(fsFile,function(){
               if(!err){
                 console.log("New image get upload")
                 }
               })
             }
          });                 
         }else{
          console.log("user don't want to change the image")
        }                
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> would that be Imagess.update(currentUserId, {$set: newFile, function(err,fileObj)?

Nope.

---

The syntax of Meteor's Mongo collection update statement is modeled after [that of mongo Shell's](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/operators/). In this case if you want to do an update, you need to specify which record to be updated in your first parameter.

```
Imagess.update({_id:theImageId},newFile);
```

In mongo, update is actually just overwriting.

This would overwrite the record in Imagess which satisfies the statement `_id:theImageId` into a new JSON object, `newFile`. But are you sure that is what you want? If you want to be able to change user's image, this statement already did it for you:

```
Meteor.users.update(currentUserId, {$set: imagesURL});
```

If that is really what you want, then you would have to somehow get the id of the Imagess data record (or any property of it) you want to update first.

Note: `insert` statement returns the id of the inserted data record.